# Confusion on Malloc behavior, why it last input is not taken?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

This is a snippet of a program I am working on. I wanted to get information from the user, where the target variable cannot have predefined memory. For some reason my function does not work for the last section of the code. Any help will be appreciated.

Current Output:

`Enter your name: Daniel`  
`Hi Danie` (expected as I put the limit to 5 characters)  
`Enter your phone number: 123456789`  
`123456789`  
`Enter your Note:`  
 (Here it breaks and does not print the `contactNote` variable.)

Here is the code:

```
char *getwords(int numberoftimes) {
    char *words = malloc(sizeof(char));
    int index = 0;
    int character = EOF;
    int size = 0;
    int increase = 1;
    int counter = 0;
    char *temp;

    while (character) {
        character = getc(stdin);
        if (numberoftimes == 0) {
            if (character == '\n') {
                character = 0;
            }
        } else if (counter == numberoftimes || character == '\n') {
            character = 0;
        }
        if (size <= index) {
            size += increase;
            temp = realloc(words, size);
            if (!temp) {
                free(words);
                words = NULL;
                break;
            }
            words = temp;
        }
        words[index++] = character;
        counter++;
    }
    return words;
}

int main() {
    char *contactName, *contactNote;
    long contactNumber;

    printf("\nEnter your name: ");
    char *getwords();
    char *Name = getwords(5);
    printf("\nHi %s\n", Name);

    printf("\nEnter your phone number: ");
    scanf("%lu", &contactNumber);
    printf("\n%lu\n", contactNumber);

    printf("\nEnter your Note: ");
    char *getwords();
    char *Note = getwords(0);
    printf("\n%s\n", Note);
}
```

Comment: And in what way does it not work? A more detailled description would be useful. "Does not work" is not helpful in any way.

Comment: You only call `malloc` once and don't even check return value. What is confusing about that?

Comment: You should write : `scanf("%lu", &contactNumber);`

Comment: Suggestion: don't malloc 1 byte! Don't realloc by increasing 1 byte! ... start with a larger malloc (like `1000`?) realloc by doubling ... if needed, when you're done realloc down to fit the data. *Mind the `'\0'` terminator*

Comment: @pmg the 0 terminator seems controlled by `character`

Comment: @DavidRanieri yeah ... I really meant when realloc'ing down (and, of course, in general when dealing with strings).

Comment: @pmg oops, yes, that's a problem

Comment: Why do you think it is related to `realloc` and not simply to your way of storing the input? Did you run the program in a debugger? Did you print `character`, `counter´ and `index` to see what is happening?

Comment: I am not supposed to preallocate memory, this is one of the conditions. What I mean is that, I can only allocate when the user adds a new character. @pmg

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to be more precise now. @Gerhardh

Comment: Phone numbers are no integers. How would you handle leading `0` or `+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` for the contact number leaves the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> sitting in the [keyboard] input buffer.

```
int main() {


    char *contactName, *contactNote;     // unused variables
    long contactNumber;

    printf("\nEnter your name: ");
    char* getwords();                    // unnecessary function declaration
    char *Name = getwords(5);
    printf("\nHi %s\n", Name);

    printf("\nEnter your phone number: ");
    scanf("%lu", &contactNumber);        // leaves <ENTER> in buffer
    printf("\n%lu\n", contactNumber);

    printf("\nEnter your Note: ");
    char* getwords();                    // unnecessary function declaration
    char *Note = getwords(0);            // empty line because of previous <ENTER>
    printf("\n%s\n", Note);

}
```

I suggest you also use `getwords()` for the number, then convert to `long` with `strtol()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I followed your suggestion and it works.

puts("\nEnter your Number: ");
 char *Number = getwords(0);
 Number = strtol(Number,endptr, 10);
 printf("\n%lu\n", Number);

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- mixing `getc()` and `scanf()` is tricky as `scanf()` leaves the trailing newline pending in `stdin` so `getc()` reads this newline immediately. You should read all of your inputs with `getwords()`.
- the extra `char *getwords();` declarations inside the body of `main()` are redundant and confusing.
- `getwords()` is too complicated, especially for exiting the loop.
- you do not always check for memory allocation error.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getwords(const char *prompt, int maxlen) {
    char *words = malloc(sizeof(char));
    int index = 0;
    int size = 0;
    char *temp;

    if (words == NULL)
        return NULL;

    printf("%s", prompt);
    for (;;) {
        int character = getc(stdin);
        if (character == EOF || character == '\n')
            break;
        if (index < maxlen) {
            if (index >= size) {
                size += 1;
                temp = realloc(words, size + 1);
                if (!temp) {
                    free(words);
                    return NULL;
                }
                words = temp;
            }
            words[index++] = character;
        }
    }
    words[index] = '\0';
    return words;
}

int main() {
    char *Name = getwords("\nEnter your name: ", 5);
    if (!Name)
        return 1;
    printf("\nHi %s\n", Name);

    char *contact = getwords("\nEnter your phone number: ", 20);
    if (!contact)
        return 1;
    long contactNumber = 0;
    sscanf(contact, "%lu", &contactNumber);
    printf("\n%lu\n", contactNumber);

    char *Note = getwords("\nEnter your Note: ", 10);
    if (!Note)
        return 1;
    printf("\n%s\n", Note);
    return 0;
}
```